# getFrameAtTime() returns Same Frame

Tags: android

I`m trying to retrieve frames from video files which are captured by camera.
I wrote a function to do so and i use it in a loop with different times ,receiving frames every 100000(micro sec) :

```
public static Bitmap getVideoFrame(long time) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever mdr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mdr.setDataSource(path);
        try {
            return mdr.getFrameAtTime((time),MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
              mdr.release();
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I know that given time must be in microseconds and i tried that.No matter what , getFrameAtTime() returns same frame all the time .

Comment: The problem could be because you use 100_000 like a sec when 1 sec = 1_000_000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem but I could not find a solution using the MediaMetadataRetriever.

However, I did using this: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, was stuck on this issue for two days! Can't believe Android's API for this has such terrible reliability.

Comment: Though i have to notify everyone that FFMMR is not reliable for all android devices and it is not efficient either.